# React Components Not Rendering List from LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs

I’m working on a React application where I have an Input and Select component for a form, and a List component to display the data. Form data is stored in local storage upon submission. In the List component, I’m trying to read this data from local storage, parse it as JSON, and display it in a list. However, the list is not visible on the screen. In fact, the whole page goes blank when I try to display the list. Here’s the code for my components:
[list component which is imported inside the form component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7i9z.png)

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    const newList = keys.map((key) => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
    setList(newList);
  }, []);

  const deleteHandler = (key) => {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    setList(list.filter((element) => element.key !== key));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map((element) => (
          <li key={element.key}>
            Key: {element.key}, Expense: {element.expense}, Price:{" "}
            {element.price}, Category: {element.category}
            <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(element.key)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

[my form component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhll.png)

```
    import { useState } from "react";

import { Input, Select } from "../Input/Input";
import List from "../List/List";

const Form = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("");
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (key !== "" && expense !== "" && price !== 0 && category !== "") {
      const data = { key, expense, price, category };
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
      setKey("");
      setExpense("");
      setPrice(0);
      setCategory("");
    } else {
      alert("fill the details first");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Key"
          value={key}
          onChange={(event) => setKey(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Expense"
          value={expense}
          onChange={(event) => setExpense(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          type="number"
          label="Price"
          value={price}
          onChange={(event) => setPrice(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Select
          label="Category"
          value={category}
          onChange={(event) => setCategory(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button onSubmit={submitHandler} type="submit">Submit✅</button>
      </form>
      <List />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I’ve tried debugging: the list still doesn’t appear. And whenever I include the list in my code the whole page goes black... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page goes blank because when rendering happens the list is empty.
You can check for undefined as follows

```
{
  list?.map((element) => (
    <li key={element.key}>
      Key: {element.key}, Expense: {element.expense}, Price: {element.price},
      Category: {element.category}
      <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(element.key)}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  ));
}
```

And also make the following change for your useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    const newList = keys
      .map((key) => {
        const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (item) {
          return JSON.parse(item);
        }
        return null;
      })
      .filter((item) => item !== null);
    setList(newList);
  }, []);
```

Edit:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("");
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [listData, setListData] = useState();

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (key !== "" && expense !== "" && price !== 0 && category !== "") {
      const data = { key, expense, price, category };
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
      setListData(data);
      setKey("");
      setExpense("");
      setPrice(0);
      setCategory("");
    } else {
      alert("fill the details first");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Key"
          value={key}
          onChange={(event) => setKey(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Expense"
          value={expense}
          onChange={(event) => setExpense(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          type="number"
          label="Price"
          value={price}
          onChange={(event) => setPrice(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Select
          label="Category"
          value={category}
          onChange={(event) => setCategory(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button onSubmit={submitHandler} type="submit">
          Submit✅
        </button>
      </form>
      <List listData={listData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

List component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const List = (props) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const listData = props.listData;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listData) {
      setList(listData);
    }
  }, [listData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    const newList = keys.map((key) => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
    setList(newList);
  }, []);

  const deleteHandler = (key) => {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    setList(list.filter((element) => element.key !== key));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map((element) => (
          <li key={element.key}>
            Key: {element.key}, Expense: {element.expense}, Price:{" "}
            {element.price}, Category: {element.category}
            <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(element.key)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Comment: when submitted, I have to reload the page to get my list shown: How do I fix this?

Comment: @qj I updated the answer. You can try that